# "Public Directory Warning - Public directory is empty" on firebase deploy

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have a firebase app with the following hosting configuration:

```
{
  "firebase": "the-world-table",
  "public": "app",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

The app directory is not empty (it has an index.html and a javascript file in it). However, when I deploy I get the following warning:

```
Preparing to deploy Public Directory...
Public Directory Warning - Public directory is empty, removing site
progress: 100%
Sucessfully removed
```

And when I browse to the static files, they aren't found. Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: wouldn't ignoring `**.*` ignore everything?

Comment: @Kato yes. See ensuing discussion below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ignore rules appear to be a little over zealous in removing files from the directory you specified to be deployed:

Instead of the default `**/.*` ignore rule which matches all files in any sub-folder that contain a `.` character, the rule you specify `**.*` matches all files in the root of the folder to be deployed that contains a `.`, which in this case caused nothing to remain. If you remove this line or add the `/` back in you should see the behavior you expect.

The [docs on the subject](https://www.firebase.com/docs/hosting/guide/full-config.html#sts=Glob%20Pattern%20Matching) cover the basics of [glob pattern matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) and offer some further references

Comment: Thanks @chris-raynor. I got this from the example in the docs and didn't look very closely at it. Might be worth updating the docs with a better example.

Answer (score 3):

firebase is looking by default in folder `public` for file `index.html`.

if in angular4 for example the `index.html` exists in folder `dist` you have to go into `firebase.json` and paste there:

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "dist"
    }
}
```

this is direct the firebase to look for `index.html` in `dist` folder or whatever is folder call instead `public`.
of cores you have that your file call `index.html`.

after that:

```
firebase deploy
```

probably will work

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're trying to deploy an empty directory.

The `public` property should correspond to where your public files, like `index.html` reside.

There are a couple of ways to fix it:

**1. Change the config to point to your public content**

Change `firebase.json` to point to the correct location. For example, if your html files are in the same directory as `firebase.json`, your config might look like this:

```
{
  "firebase": "the-world-table",
  "public": ".",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

**2. Make the directory structure match your config**

Here's an example directory structure that would work with your `firebase.json` config:

```
- project/
   - README.md
   - firebase.json
   - app/
       - index.html
```

Comment: Thanks @jenny-tong. I actually do have my app organized like you describe in option 2. The app dir contains an index.html file and a javascript file, which is why I'm confused that it's not working.

Comment: Please see my comment below @jenny-tong. Looks like I found a bug in firebase-tools.

Answer (score 1):

Change the below code in your firebase.json if you your index.html is in a public folder

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./"
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Looks like my firebase.json discovered a bug in firebase-tools. The files specified in the "ignore" section are treated as though they were relative to the directory specified in "public". If you specify non-existent files in your "ignore" section, it will halt before even beginning the deployment and give an error like the one above.

Comment: If you've found a bug in Firebase, please contact the Firebase support team so we can get it fixed: https://www.firebase.com/docs/help/#section-request

Comment: OK, I've submitted an email describing the bug.

Comment: Thanks much! I'll update my answer once we get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @JennyTong it looks like it was my mistake for grabbing an example from the docs without looking closely at it. Might be worth updating the docs to avoid this though.